# Align two blocks within a div that is itself aligned centrally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a div with a width of 1000px and then within said div align a piece of text 10px from the left edge and align an image directly in the middle, but I am having trouble. The text is pushed off the left of the screen and the image is situated to the left of the screen.

I don't understand what I've done wrong here. I'm sure the solution is mind-bogglingly obvious, and I'm just being thick.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color:red;
}

div#headerinner {
position: relative;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 1000px;
}

img.header {
position:absolute;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

span#login {
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="headerinner">
<span id="login">Welcome!</span>

<img class="header" src="mysite/heading.png" alt="Header">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you set position:absolute you cant set margin-left: auto; and margin-right: auto; for that element. so

```
img.header {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `position:absolute` from this `class` `img.header`

```
img.header {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kudQ9/1/)